# Multithreading in Java across different tasks but not same path

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a queue where a producer would submit tasks. Each task has a payload along with a file path. On the consumer side, I have an Executor Thread Pool which should pick up tasks from the queue and assign these to threads. The following are some constraints that need to be followed:

1. We cannot have more than one thread working on the same file path
2. We want the tasks added for a particular file path to be done in order

Here is an example of the problem statement. Let's suppose the following is the state of the queue. Here T1 is thread name and the brackets contain the file path.
`head -> [T1(A),T2(B),T3(C),T4(A),T5(B),T6(A),T7(A),T8(C)] <- tail`

So we can have three threads working on tasks for file paths `A`,`B` and `C` simultaneously. However, the following **should not happen**. Here file path `A` has two threads working on it at the same time.
`Pool1-Thread1-T4(A)`
`Pool1-Thread2-T5(B)`
`Pool1-Thread3-T6(A)`
The number of file paths can range anywhere between `10k-50k`

To resolve this, the approach I have come up with is to have two maps, that is `Map<String, Queue<Tasks>>` for Tasks Queue and a `Map<String, AtomicBoolean>` for Tokens, both of which have keys against *file paths*. A single running consumer thread that would keep iterating over the `Tasks Map` and would need to obtain a token(Boolean should be true) for that *file path* before it creates a thread for that path. Once a thread completes, it returns the Token(by marking Boolean back to `true`).

**Question**

- Is this the best approach for this use case or we can do something better and/or simpler ?
- Are there any multi threading concerns in this approach that might bite me later ?

**Edit**

1. Clarifying how tasks will be picked up. I will have a single running consumer thread that would keep iterating over the `Tasks Map`. If it finds any task and a token available, it would spawn a new thread from the executor.
2. The tasks themselves are small but throughput of incoming tasks will be high. The file paths here are representative of cloned git repo's and tasks can be for example adding files, modifying files, committing and pushing to remote.

Comment: Are you synchronizing when you updating a Queue?

Comment: Once the task is submitted to a Executor we cannot be sure which thread will be assigned to execute the task. A per file Single threaded approach will not work as there could be large number of files. We need to check if we can extend the executor service to add functionality for assigning tasks having common file path to a single thread.  How big is your task? How time complex is the task?  May be we can Isolate functionality based on time complexity.

Comment: @Gunwant I have added some more information around producer and nature of tasks

Comment: @arjunkhera I do not understand the meaning of "Executor creates a thread for that path".  Do you mean to say, if the token is false, the task will not be submitted to executor ?

Comment: @Gunwant yes. The token being false would indicate that a thread is already working on that path and hence we should not spawn a new thread for the same path

Comment: @arjunkhera What I understood, please correct me if I am wrong.  Task ->T1,T2...Tn. File->f1,f2...fn , Thread -> Th1, Th2,... Thn. Where n tends to 10k~50k. Tasks T1(f1),T2(f1),T3(f1).. can have business with file F1 and all the business with F1 has to be executed sequentially in the timed manner.  If Th1 is working on T1(f1),  another thread Th3 cannot work on T2(f1). Only if Th1 is done execution, Th3 can start work on T2(f1).  Execution order has to be maintain i.e. T1(f1) shall be done before T2(f1) shall be done before T3(f1) . Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Gunwant you got it correct. Although it is preferable if we do not create Th3 in the first place if we know Th1 is working on f1. That is one thread for a file at a given time always.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234569/discussion-between-gunwant-and-arjunkhera).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using the Executor thread pool and use the following approach:

- create a class with a BlockingXXXQueue (choose the implementation) and a thread that continuously consumes from this queue. It will consume Tasks obviously. When it fetches a task it will execute it. This gives you the guarantee that tasks in the queue are executed sequentially and at most one from this queue is being executed.
- now create some logic that maps tasks to queues. E.g. if you don't want tasks of the same type to be executed at the same time, map them
  all to the same queue. For example A will always go to queue 1, B to 2, etc... It follows the property mentioned before that in this way no 2 tasks of type A will go in parallel.

An common way to do this is to put all queues in an array and then assign according to some value modulo the number of queues, this is calling **partitioning**, example:

```
queues = new Queue[N];

typeOfTask = task.getType() (to int somehow, for example you can hash or use the char if it is a single letter)

queueIndex = typeTask % queues.length

queues[queueIndex].push(task)
```

- in the classes above you can do any logic when fetching tasks before passing them to the thread, like what you mentioned.

as a final note, I would avoid using many threads (if any at all) when using the filesystem, because the disk is... one. So no big point working on it in parallel, unless you have to write a lot of data that you don't want to buffer. Instead, threading is more about being able to work in parallel using more processors to get a speed up or when doing blocking operations.

Comment: I was going to fetch tasks from a continuously running thread which would then spawn a new thread for given task from executor. I have updated my question to clarify this. And yes, they would work on disk. Actually, these file paths are cloned git repos and I would want to add, commit, etc on different repo's simultaneously since work one does not block another

Comment: I had considered the modulo approach, but the paths are not static. They can increase and decrease hence I decided to go with a `Map`

Comment: what do you mean with paths being not static? if they are strings you can do hashCode() on them and you get a number, then use it to modulo. I advise not to use threads to access the filesystem. I would use a single thread...

Comment: You are using `queues` length to modulo. If `queues` length changes, then `queueIndex` will also change for same hash. As for single thread while using filesystem. I will keep this mind and compare both solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, queues and threads should remain the same throughout the lifetime of the application. I would avoid spawning a new thread for task, if you do that probably you should consider a different design because that's not very efficient

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement a part of consumer use case, it seems there are more questions than solutions. Please read inline comments in the code.

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean isStopped;
    private final Map<String, Queue<Task>> tasks;
    private final Map<String, AtomicBoolean> tokens;
    //Preferably FixedThreadService
    private final ExecutorService service;


    public Consumer(Map<String, Queue<Task>> tasks, Map<String, AtomicBoolean> tokens, ExecutorService service) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        this.tokens = tokens;
        this.service = service;
        isStopped = false;
    }

    public void stopConsumer(){
        isStopped = true;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!isStopped){
            // tasks map should have latest values because producer is going to update this map
            // frequently. Should have to use ConcurrentHashMap.
            Set<String> keys = tasks.keySet();
            for ( String key:tasks.keySet() ) {
                if(!tokens.get(key).get()){
                    continue;
                }
              try {
                  //This does not mean the task is in progress, just submitted for execution.
                  service.execute(tasks.get(key).poll());
                  //Now that we submitted the task for exicution, we can mark the token to false.
                  tokens.get(key).compareAndSet(true, false);
                  // But at what point are we going to mark token to True. If this token is updated
                  // From any other thread than consumer, it will create race condition.
              }catch(RejectedExecutionException e){
                  //What will happen to the polled task. Task is removed from the queue.
                  
                  //Token we can mark to true, but task has already polled from queue.
                  // Shall we put it back to the head of the queue and how ?
                  tokens.get(key).compareAndSet(false, true);
                  //What if the task is not completed smoothly. T1 is not completed successfully,
                  // what is backup plan, because next task will start any way and corrupt the file.

              }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If we can isolate the tasks like  1. adding files, 2, modifying files, 3. committing and 4. pushing to remote, may be we can think better way. But there will constraints in that case too.

Better go with Single Threaded approach.